# Need help in overcoming this exception

Tags: exception

I am running into this exception when running my test class:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, portal users cannot own partner accounts

I am creating the portal user as follows in test class

```
@isTest
class CreateUserControllerTest{

    static testmethod void csaAdminCreateUser(){

        User csaUsr = getPortalUser('Customer Portal Standard User', null, true, 'en_US', 'en_US');

        //Give CSA permissions to the user to create a new user

        ceateCSAPermissionsets(csaUsr.Id);

        UserAccount__c[] cpUsrAct = [Select Account__c, Account__r.N__c from UserAccount__c where User__c =:csaUsr.Id];

        System.runAs(csaUsr){

            PageReference pageRef = Page.AdminCreateUser;

            Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

            Test.startTest();

            AdminController adminCtrl = new AdminController();
            AdminController.UserObj obj = new AdminController.UserObj();
                obj.firstName = 'firstNameTest';
                obj.lastName  = 'lastNameTest';
                obj.jobTitle  = 'jobTitleTest';
                obj.Telephone = '12345678909';
                obj.email   = TestUtil.generateRandomEmail();
                obj.Country   ='Country';
                obj.Region    ='Region';
                obj.language  ='language';
                obj.active    =true;

            for(UserAccount__c cp:cpUsrAct){
                AdminController.CcansWrapper can=new AdminController.ccWrapper(cp.Account__r.N__c,cp.Account__c);
                adminCtrl.cansList.add(can);
            }
            List<AdminController.ccWrapper> filterList=new List<AdminController.ccWrapper>();

            for(AdminController.ccWrapper cw:adminCtrl.cansList){
                cw.flag =true;
                filterList.add(cw);
            }
            //System.assertEquals(adminCtrl.cansList.size(), adminCtrl.cansList.size() >0);

            AdminController.CreateUserRemote(obj, filterList);
            Test.stopTest();

            //Contact[] cnt=[Select id, email from Contact where Name =: 'firstNameTest lastNameTest' limit 1];
            //System.assertEquals(cnt[0].email, '');
        }
                } 

    public static User getPortalUser(String portalType, User userWithRole, Boolean doInsert, string lang, string loc)
    {
        if (userWithRole == null) {
            if (UserInfo.getUserRoleId() == null) {
                UserRole r = new UserRole(name = 'TEST ROLE');
                Database.insert(r);
                userWithRole = new User(Username = 'TestUSe@test.com', CommunityNickname = 'TestCommunityNickName123',
                                        alias = 'hasrole', email = TestUtil.generateRandomEmail(), userroleid = r.id,
                                        emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', lastname = 'Testing123', languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                                        localesidkey = 'en_US', profileid = UserInfo.getProfileId(),CP_User_Country__c='United Kingdom',
                                        timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles', Business_Unit__c = 'EM'
                );
            } else {
                userWithRole = new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId(), UserRoleId = UserInfo.getUserRoleId());
            }
            System.assert(userWithRole.userRoleId != null,
                'This test requires the target org to have at least one UserRole created. Please create a user role in this organization and try again.');
        }

        Account a; 
        Contact c;

        Contact_Account__c cpContAct;
        UserAccount__c cpua;
        System.runAs(userWithRole) {
            a =createAccount('Test account1', '1234');
            Database.insert(a);
            c = createContact(a.Id);
            Database.insert(c);
            c.Portal_User__c = true;
            c.Assigned__c = true;
            update c;
            cpContAct = createCPContactAccount(a.Id, c.Id);
           Database.insert(cpContAct);
        }

        Profile p = [select id from profile where Name = 'Customer Portal Standard User' limit 1];
        User pusr = new User(profileId = p.id, username = 'TestUse@tes.com', email = Utill.generateRandomEmail(), CommunityNickname = 'Test Community780',
                           emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', localesidkey = loc,CP_User_Country__c='United Kingdom', 
                           languagelocalekey = lang, timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                           alias = 'cspu089', lastname = 'lastname789', contactId = c.id);

        return pusr;
    }

    public static Account createAccount(String actName, String ccan){

       Id recId=[Select Id from RecordType where Name ='DFS Customer Account Record Type'].Id;

        Account act=new Account(RecordTypeId = recId, Name = actName, N__c = ccan, Business_Unit__c = 'US', Type = 'Customer', Segment__c = 'PUBLIC', SubSegment__c = 'HCLS', Status__c = 'Active');

        return act;
    } 

    public static Contact createContact(Id accId){

        Id recId=[Select Id from RecordType where Name ='DFS Contact Record Type'].Id;

        Contact cnt=new Contact(AccountId = accId, lastname = 'lastname', firstname = 'firstname', RecordTypeId = recId, Contact_Roles__c='Other', Preferred_Language__c ='English');      

        return cnt;
    }


    public static Contact_Account__c createCPContactAccount(Id accId, Id cntId){

        ContactAccount__c cpCntAct=new ContactAccount__c(Account__c = accId,Contact__c = cntId);

        return cpCntAct;
    }


   public static UserAccount__c createCPUserAccount(Id acctId, Id userId){

        UserAccount__c cpua = new UserAccount__c(Name='TEST', Account__c = acctId, User__c = userId);

        return cpua;
    }

    public static void ceateCSAPermissionsets(Id userId){

        User usr= CreateSystemAdmin('en_US', 'en_US');

        system.runAs(usr){

            PermissionSet[] permission = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'Customer_Portal_CSA'];

            PermissionSetAssignment assignedPerm = new PermissionSetAssignment ( PermissionSetId = permission[0].Id, AssigneeId = userId);
            Database.Insert(assignedPerm); 
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: To start with your code is not valid

Comment: @Eric I edited my questuion with my actual test class code

Comment: It would be helpful if you could indicate from where this `DmlException` is being thrown...

Comment: I saw this DML exception in Debug logs it didnt throw an error and not create a contact record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this exception is the owner of the parent account should be the owner of the contact created by the customer portal standard user.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the error message you're receiving and that you're using a portal User for the "RunAs" User, it appears to me that you're trying to have a portal User create an Account that's associated with the Partner Account RecordType. That can only be done by a Salesforce User.

I suggest you check your record types and then use a RunAs User who's a Standard User or an Admin User to create your Portal User. After that, you can then use the Portal User to do the remainder of your tests.